# WM_SIZE and MoveWindow

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

Will someone look at this code.  is there a different formula for moving STATIC controls when you Resize the window.  I have a `ChatRoomMessages` variable that holds handles created later in the code.  there is a variable that holds their y position at time of `CreateWindow` so i traverse them in the same position.  I need it to get `ChatRoomMessages[i]` and `y[i]` (which is the y position in the `RECT`) and move the window when it resizes.  I can upload the code to you if you want or email.  If this is not appropriate for the site please delete my bad algorithm.  If you can suggest a solution that would be great.

```
HWND ChatRoomMessages[100];

int y[100];

case WM_SIZING:
{
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &sizingRect);
}
case WM_SIZE:
{

    signed int y1;
    RECT sizingRect2;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &sizingRect2);
    if ((sizingRect2.bottom - sizingRect.bottom) > 0) {

        for (int x1 = 0; x1 < 100; x1++)
        {
            //MessageBox(hWnd2, L"WM_SIZE Called", L"Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONQUESTION);
            y[x1] -= (sizingRect2.bottom - sizingRect.bottom) - (j*100);
            MoveWindow((HWND)ChatRoomMessages[x1], 0, y[x1], sizingRect2.right - 50, 100, TRUE);

        }
    }
    else {


    }
```

Comment: I found out VS was adding in inline functions from a previous compile.. it's up and working now.  thanks anyways.

Comment: Did you add breaks? `case WM_SIZING:... break;`

Comment: I thought WM_SIZING was right befote the window resizes but it must be something else because i moved the get client rect to the end of WM_SIZE. The program started.. Called all the functions at that point and when i processed it a second time it was ideal how easy it worked.  I was so confused thank you for your answer.  Never noticed i forgot breaks.

Answer (score 0):

- 1)  Visual Studio wasn't recompiling my functions. so i had to clean build
- 2)  I was getting the sizingRect from WM_SIZING. I put it at the very bottom of my WM_SIZE and when it recalls (even from when it starts obviously) there are 2 rectangles.  i did that and used simply

`y[i] = y[i] + (sizingRect2.bottom - sizingRect.bottom);`